# Managed Metadata Navigation displays active child items without parents

Tags: managed-metadata, managed-navigation

Summary: I would like the menu not to show all menu items, and not to shrink down to a single child item when selecting it. Is there a quick way to accomplish this?

Here is what I have done:

I have set up Managed Metadata Navigation using the option "Term-Driven Page with Friendly URL". Using "Target Page Settings", I have specified target pages for each navigation term. All target pages are within the same page library, in the same site. When looking at the result, it showed exactly what I was looking for. The current navigation shows the tree structure of terms that I created:

[image: The current navigation has many levels]

When clicking on "subterm1", the headaches begin. For some reason it shrinks the menu to only show the clicked item. I would still like to see the items on the level above the current item.

[image: The current navigation has shrinked to only one level]

In order to accomplish this, I know that I can create a completely new control which I reference in the master page. but my question is: does anyone know if there is a setting that does not shrink the menu?

Comment: Maybe this solution will be useful https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118329/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation-show-parent-term/118602

Answer (score 0):

**For all the Subsites**

On the Site Settings page -> under Look and Feel -> click Navigation.

In the Current Navigation section, click **Display the same navigation items as the parent site.**

PS: If you don't see Navigation under Look and Feel, you might need to activate Publishing Infrastructure Feature on your Site Collection and Site level..

Reference:

[Customize the navigation on your team site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/customize-the-navigation-on-your-team-site-HA103532378.aspx#_Toc338406286) -- It says team site but applies to all Publishing Sites

Comment: This option has no effect I am afraid. I think you misunderstood my question. The sub term is not a sub web, it is just a navigation node below another one in the term store.

Comment: Oh.. than it shouldn't behave like this.. weird..