# Sharepoint 2013 metadata navigation show parent term

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, term-store

At my site I am using term store metadata navigation for left navigation panel. The problem is - when I have navigated to "Level 1.2.1", I want to show parent of this level (like in example below).

```
()Root
  () Level 1
    () Level 1.1
    () Level 1.2   <-- I want to show this either
      () Level 1.2.1  <-- I can show this
      () Level 1.2.2  <-- I am here
      () Level 1.2.3  <-- I can show this
   () Level 2
```

Right now I can show siblings of current term - for example, if I am at "Level 1.2.2", I can see 1.2.1 and 1.2.3, but I need to show 1.2 !
I want to avoid breadcrumb, so that showing parent term would be a possibility to navigate through site.

Navigation is coded in layout page:

```
<SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
ID="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"
runat="server"
QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
EnableViewState="False">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
    <Template_Controls>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource
             SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" 
             ID="QuickLaunchSiteMap" 
             runat="server" 
             EnableViewState="False" 
             ShowStartingNode="True" 
             StartFromCurrentNode="False" 
             StartingNodeOffset="-1" />
    </Template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
<SharePoint:AspMenu 
    Width="100%" 
    CssClass="sidebar" 
    ID="V4QuickLaunchMenu" 
    runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="False" 
    DataSourceID="QuickLaunchSiteMap" 
    UseSimpleRendering="true" 
    Orientation="Vertical" 
    StaticDisplayLevels="3" 
    RenderingMode="List" 
    AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" 
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" 
    SkipLinkText="">
</SharePoint:AspMenu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I found solution for this problem by myself.

Problem was with attribute **ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource"**, that was overriding part of my attributes in *SiteMapDataSource*.

ControlId is a part of navigation feature,that stores settings in *NavigationSiteSettings.xml*

It is located in *C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Navigatio*n

In my case, I removed reference *ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource"* from *DelegateControl* and updated my *SiteMapDataSouce* code block:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource
  SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider" 
  ID="QuickLaunchSiteMap" 
  runat="server" 
  EnableViewState="False"  
  ShowStartingNode="True" 
  StartFromCurrentNode="False" 
  StartingNodeOffset="1"  />
```

Comment: Could you please provide the source for the whole SPNavigationManager?

Comment: Whole SPNavigationManager tag code is showed in post. There are only two changes : removed reference _ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource"_ from _DelegateControl_ tag and updated _SiteMapDataSouce_ tag -  _SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider"_.