# Parent items not showing in quick launch with friendly URLs

Tags: sharepoint-server, quick-launch, managed-navigation

I have enabled Term driven navigation in a sub site. 
When I use friendly URLs and visits a sub level in the hierarchy no parent levels are shown just the selected page and its siblings. This only happens when I use friendly URLs. If i switch back to "Simple Link or Header" the quick launch menu shows all parent levels.

How can I get the full menu when using friendly urls?

Comment: I found this solution https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118329/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation-show-parent-term/118602

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to edit the page layout and the master page in order to change the behavior of the menu but nothing helped. Then I found a blog post about an **xml-file** on the server that had the same settings.

When I made changes to that file the menu worked as I wanted. It is probably not the best practice way because it involves editing a standard SharePoint file on the server, but it worked...

This is the file:

> 15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Navigation\NavigationSiteSettings.xml

Comment: Good day, I have the same problem. Could you give the link to the blog post about xml-file on server, please? Which changes did you make to the file NavigationSiteSettings.xml ?