# SharePoint Friendly URL can't see parent terms

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, url, term, collection

Good day,

I created Term Set for site collection.

I use term set for Site Collection Navigation. The terms include friendly URL for some subsite pages. If I open first level friendly URL, I see First Level terms. If I open second Level friendly URL, I can't see First Level terms. This problem is actual with friendly URL only.
How can I make second Level friendly URL see First Level terms?
Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean not able to see the second level terms?

Per my test, the second level terms friendly URL is based on the first level:

[image]

When I click the sub term navigation, it will also show the parent term:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found this information https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118329/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation-show-parent-term/118602

Comment: Did you code the navigation before? Which I said is the OOB term set navigation, it will show the parent term when you select subterm.